# I am getting 500 internal sever error (XDMP-CHILDNODEKIND) while processing ZIP

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

We have rest extension for which one of the parameter for post  method is zip that we want to process but I am getting error 500. following message displayed in response. ZIP consist of some json and images and pdf. is there any workaround to make it run.

here is situation i have reproduced what I have got same in PROD Environment:

extension code:

```
declare 
%roxy:params("")
%rapi:transaction-mode("update")
function dmc:post(
    $context as map:map,
    $params  as map:map,
    $input   as document-node()*
) as document-node()*
{
  let $_ := xdmp:log("**********")
  let $_ := xdmp:log($context)
  let $_ := xdmp:log("**********")

  let $_ := xdmp:log("**********")
  let $_ := xdmp:log($params)
  let $_ := xdmp:log("**********")

  let $_ := xdmp:log("**********")
  let $_ := xdmp:log($input)
  let $_ := xdmp:log("**********")

  let $_ := xdmp:log("**********")
  let $_ := xdmp:log(xdmp:get-request-field-content-type("rs:file"))
  let $_ := xdmp:log("**********")

  let $_ := map:put($context, "output-types", "application/xml")
  let $_ := map:put($context, "output-status", (201, "Created"))
  let $name := map:get($params, "name")
  let $file := map:get($params, "file")
  return document{c:my-function($name, $file)}
};
```

module code :

```
declare function c:my-function($name as xs:string, $file as binary()) as xs:string{

    let $my-name := $name
    let $my-file := $file
    return $my-name
};
```

error log:

```
2020-02-20 20:57:04.530 Info: **********
2020-02-20 20:57:04.530 Info: {"input-types":"multipart/form-data"}
2020-02-20 20:57:04.530 Info: **********
2020-02-20 20:57:04.530 Info: **********
2020-02-20 20:57:04.531 Info: {"file":["", "504b0304140000000800339fa94a56184dfee3850000209000001a00000000a882994a20b6abbe41000000410000000a00000000000000010020000000a38e0000617373656c2e6a736f6e504b05060000000003000300b90000000c8f00000000"], "name":"shrikant"}
2020-02-20 20:57:04.531 Info: **********
2020-02-20 20:57:04.531 Info: **********
2020-02-20 20:57:04.531 Info: **********
2020-02-20 20:57:04.531 Info: **********
2020-02-20 20:57:04.531 Info: application/x-zip-compressed
2020-02-20 20:57:04.531 Info: **********
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice: XDMP-AS: (err:XPTY0004) $file as binary() -- Invalid coercion: "" as binary()
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+in /config/config.xqy, at 21:60,
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+in xdmp:function(fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/MyExtension","post"), "/marklogic.rest.resource/MyExtension/assets/resource.xqy")(map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>), map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>...XDMP-CHILDNODEKIND: element nodes cannot have binary node children...), document{binary{""}}) [1.0-ml]
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+in /MarkLogic/rest-api/lib/extensions-util.xqy, at 905:44,
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+in extut:call-service("MyExtension", "POST", xdmp:function(fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/MyExtension","post"), "/marklogic.rest.resource/MyExtension/assets/resource.xqy"), map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>), map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>...XDMP-CHILDNODEKIND: element nodes cannot have binary node children...), document{binary{""}}) [1.0-ml]
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $extension-name = "MyExtension"
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $method = "POST"
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $service = xdmp:function(fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/MyExtension","post"), "/marklogic.rest.resource/MyExtension/assets/resource.xqy")
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $context = map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>)
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $service-params = map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>...XDMP-CHILDNODEKIND: element nodes cannot have binary node children...)
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $input = document{binary{""}}
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+in /MarkLogic/rest-api/lib/extensions-util.xqy, at 858:20,
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+in function() as item()*() [1.0-ml]
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+in /MarkLogic/rest-api/lib/extensions-util.xqy,
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+in xdmp:invoke(function() as item()*, <options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><isolation>different-transaction</isolation>...</options>) [1.0-ml]
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+in /MarkLogic/rest-api/lib/extensions-util.xqy, at 856:12,
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+in extut:invoke-service("MyExtension", "POST", "query", xdmp:function(fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/MyExtension","post"), "/marklogic.rest.resource/MyExtension/assets/resource.xqy"), map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>), map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>...XDMP-CHILDNODEKIND: element nodes cannot have binary node children...), document{binary{""}}, fn:false()) [1.0-ml]
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $extension-name = "MyExtension"
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $method = "POST"
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $default-txn-mode = "query"
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $service = xdmp:function(fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/MyExtension","post"), "/marklogic.rest.resource/MyExtension/assets/resource.xqy")
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $context = map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>)
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $service-params = map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>...XDMP-CHILDNODEKIND: element nodes cannot have binary node children...)
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $input = document{binary{""}}
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $in-txn = fn:false()
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $txn-curr = "query"
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $txn-mode = "update"
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+in /MarkLogic/rest-api/models/resource-model-query.xqy, at 269:20,
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+in rsrcmodqry:resource-post("MyExtension", map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>), map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>...XDMP-CHILDNODEKIND: element nodes cannot have binary node children...), document{binary{""}}, fn:false(), local:rsrcmod-callback#6) [1.0-ml]
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $resource-name = "MyExtension"
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $context = map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>)
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $resource-params = map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>...XDMP-CHILDNODEKIND: element nodes cannot have binary node children...)
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $input = document{binary{""}}
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $in-txn = fn:false()
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $responder = local:rsrcmod-callback#6
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $service = xdmp:function(fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/MyExtension","post"), "/marklogic.rest.resource/MyExtension/assets/resource.xqy")
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+in /MarkLogic/rest-api/models/resource-model-query.xqy, at 236:4,
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+in rsrcmodqry:exec-post(map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>), map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>...XDMP-CHILDNODEKIND: element nodes cannot have binary node children...), document{binary{""}}, local:rsrcmod-callback#6) [1.0-ml]
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $headers = map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>)
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $endpoint-params = map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>...XDMP-CHILDNODEKIND: element nodes cannot have binary node children...)
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $input = document{binary{""}}
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $responder = local:rsrcmod-callback#6
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+in /MarkLogic/rest-api/endpoints/resource-service-query.xqy, at 78:8 [1.0-ml]
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $headers = map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>)
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $method = "POST"
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $body = document{binary{""}}
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $params = map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>...XDMP-CHILDNODEKIND: element nodes cannot have binary node children...)
2020-02-20 20:57:04.537 Notice:+  $extra-names = ()
2020-02-20 20:57:04.542 Info: Status 500: XDMP-AS: (err:XPTY0004) $file as binary() -- Invalid coercion: "" as binary()
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the REST extension here, please?

Comment: Actually, I'm just taking zip as  $param in post method and returning just response message.. that's it.. still it is throwing same error

Comment: zip ends up to be a child node somewhere in the process, it seems. Why would you want to process a zip file with a database, in the first place?

Comment: So should I take zip into $input separate and other parameters in $params ?? That's what I understand because currently $params is map:map in which one key is file and value would be zip file. So that's why is it throwing error? Same is working for ML9 but as a part of upgrade to ML10 this api is throwing error.. but working in ML9

Comment: Try doing a POST request and adding the zip file as body/payload. Its failing in ML 10 because of strengthening security - to prevent possible misuse of the APIs. It’s not an error, it’s by design.

Comment: still same error, just posted in more details. will it help now @SašaM

Comment: This has already been answered, check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56170819/query-generate-xdmp-childnodekind-final-element-nodes-cannot-have-binary-n

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear here - you can’t have child nodes with binary content i.e. can’t put an image as a child node of an XML document, for example

This has been already answered in more detail:
[Query generate 'XDMP-CHILDNODEKIND: $final -- element nodes cannot have binary node children' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56170819/query-generate-xdmp-childnodekind-final-element-nodes-cannot-have-binary-n/56173443#56173443)